# ¿Porqué cuando pongo es like '311%', me inserta todos los números de la consulta y no sólo los que comiencen por 311?

Tags: sqlite

INSERT INTO  unificado (mov)
SELECT Todos_telefonos FROM  clientes_Base2  where Todos_telefonos like'311%'

antes para otro caso me habia funcionado asi tal cual y solo me insertaba los que le especificaba en el like''

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que veo es que la query está funcionando correctamente, está insertando los que empiezan por '311'. O a qué te refieres exactamente? Otra consulta, esa separación de ' | ' se refiere a otras filas insertadas o es parte de la la columna 'todos_telefonos'?

Comment: ¿El contenido de _todos_telefonos_ es una cadena que está separada con `|` o hiciste un select especial? No olvides proveer un [repro] en la pregunta, y darle formato tanto a la consulta como a los datos de ejemplo.

Comment: Los datos que muestras comienzan todos por 311. Si son una cadena separada por `|` y quieres separar eso y buscar cada elemento, eso es ooooooooooootra cosa y tu consulta no hace nada de eso

Comment: es que por ejemplo en la 1 fila  si empeza por 311 pero en la otra columna despues de la separacion ya comienza es por 320( ese es el problema)

Comment: Pero ahí se ve como si fuera una sola fila. En todo caso que no quieras que el '311' aparezca en toda la fila le pones `NOT LIKE '%311%'`; en cualquier caso puedes poder un ejemplo replicable?

Comment: lo que quiero es que me inserte solo los que comiencen por 310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,300,301,302,303,304,305